# Why does Magento give us the option to disable Form Key Validation on Checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9

I've noticed Magento provides us with Form Key validation on Login, Registration and Checkout pages.

However only in the Checkout are we given the option to disable Form Key Validation.

My question is: *why does this option exist?*

In what scenario would we want to disable Form Key Validation and why are we only given that option for the checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this option allows you to override the way the checkout templates work with the latest Magento 1.9 version; this new version will make use of a form key in your checkout templates so that your site is less vulnerable to malicious attacks. The key is an input field physically added in the new templates shipped with the Magento version 1.9

This form key is a valuable improvement but as you may have experienced it in the past. If your site is customised or using a custom theme, you may not want to use this feature even though it appears a great idea.

I allow myself to repeat myself, the danger is in the event your site has modified the checkout template into a theme or also if your site uses a custom theme, **the setting can potentially break your checkout and therefore stop your customers in the site to place orders.**

To allow site's owner to be versatile with the setting, you can disable it (not recommended of course) so that it buys you some time to update your theme or template I'd say